# Widget problem in ue4; How to make a widget show when a key is pressed from the keyboard?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal

Recently, Im trying to create a scope(with widget) in UE4 and it doesnt show on when a certain key is pressed(in this case K). What I was wondering is if its possible to attach a certain actor component to a pawn or any other method?

I have tried to attach the widget(scope) to the gun, which is an actor and still doesnt work appropiateley. Also Ive tried to create a child actor component in the gun blueprint to attach it to the pawn(which is a tanand still not the expected resdult. Do you have any advice?

Comment: Could you please do all of the following: 1. Correct any spelling mistakes in your question, because currently, I don't understand the last paragraph. 2. Explain what you mean with "attach the widget to the gun", because UUserWidgets can't be "attached" to Actors. 3. How do you show other UI elements? Couldn't the scope be shown like they are?